# Migration of Weblogic Portal with NetUIX from bea weblogic server to JBoss

Tags: jboss, migration, weblogic, portal, netui

I am having a project where we want to migrate from WebLogic Server to JBoss.

The project is WebPortal Build using Beehive and NetUI, NetUIX xml portal/portlets.

Is it possible to migrate those directly to Jboss with very limited changes to view like the entire structure can be reused in view which is defined in .portal files.

I also doubt that we can use tiles instead of using portals in JBoss, as Tiles when getting loaded in browser are not going to call to individual controller's begin methods and load default content from there.

I request you to please help me find solution for this migration problem.

Thanks,
Amit

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, the migration from weblogic portal to jboss required a rewrite of the entire application.

If you are using weblogic portal (perhaps a 9.x version since you mentioned netui), i.e. the portal framework on top of weblogic server, there are far too many libraries specific to the portal framework p13n and netui alike that requires migration with no guarantee that these will be supported in Jboss. 
Likely to face trouble retrieving entitlements from the p13n jars for users.
Regarding netui beehive, I think that is retired now (not sure), but I didn't got much support for it besides there are more lightweight frameworks out there that can help.